# Initialize multiple empty vectors at once

Tags: r

I want to initialize several identical (empty) vectors before feeding them into a loop.

For instance, what I do is

```
a <- c()
b <- c()
c <- c()
d <- c()
...
```

Is there a more *compact* way to do this (one-liner ideally)?

I would imagine something like:

```
(a, b, c, d, ...) <- c() # not working
```

Comment: Maybe `a <- b <- c <- c()`, but why? What is the next step?

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks! I edited my post. I have many variables and want to have a more "compact" script.

Comment: If you explain your need for loop and show us bigger picture, most of the cases there is no need for "initialisation".

Comment: Well, then I guess I must understand R better! I thought this was the right way. Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

`a <- b <- c <- c()`

But as mentioned in the comments, we should probably re-think our approach.

**David Arenburg:**

> There is no need to initialize empty strings in *R*. You usually will pre-allocate a vector of some length in order to populate it within a loop. I have a feeling that this is exactly what you are going to do: create empty strings and then **grow them in a loop**.
>
> This is **not** a recommended approach in *R*

Comment: Even `setNames(vector(mode = "list", 3), letters[1:3])` would be better. Note that the byte code compiler makes growing objects in a loop less of an issue.